# To apply mulitple criteria in lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, c#-3.0

I have two main tables `Listings` and `Place` . In listing table there is a field `PlaceId` which referes to a Place entity/row/object . I want to query on both tables so that i get both of them like this .

```
 var query = context.Listings
       .Include("Place")
       .Where(l => l.Place.TypeId == Type.Ro)
       .OrderBy(l => l.Id).ToList();
```

after this now i want to put some filter on this query , here is the condition .

i got only a string like this `var filter = "1,2,4";` . Now i want to filter on listing to gett all these listing where bedroom is equal to 1 OR 2 OR 4 .

What i have done

```
 string minBeds = "1,2,4";

 foreach (var item in minBeds.Split(','))
 {
      int minBed = int.Parse(item);
      query = query.Where(l=>l.Place.Bedroom == minBed).ToList();
 }
```

But doing this is giving me Zero result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the way you're filtering it. After the first pass, you're filtering out everything except where `Bedroom == 1`, on the second pass you're filtering out everything except where `Bedroom == 2`, but since the only items in the list have `Bedroom == 1`, you won't have anything in the result set.

The solution is to use the conventional C# `||` operator:

```
query = query.Where(l => l.Place.Bedroom == "1" || 
                         l.Place.Bedroom == "2" || 
                         l.Place.Bedroom == "4");
```

Or if you want to be more flexible, use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method:

```
string[] minBeds = "1,2,4".Split(',');
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom));
```

Note if `Bedroom` is an integer, you'll need to convert the input to an appropriate type first:

```
var minBeds = "1,2,4".Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom));
```

Also note, I've eliminated the `ToList` here. Unless you *need* to access items by index and add / remove items from the result collection, it's most likely just a waste of resources. You can usually rely on Linq's native laziness to delay processing to query until you really need the result.

Comment: filter string is not static it could be anything from `1-4` . It could be `1,3` `1,4,2` or anything

Comment: I have asked another question related to this one . Can you help me a bit more . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419346/how-to-apply-mulitple-criteria-in-lambda-expression-in-c-sharp-along-with-greate