# How to apply mulitple criteria in lambda expression in c# along with greater then criteria

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, c#-3.0

I am Continuing my question [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418142/to-apply-mulitple-criteria-in-lambda-expression-in-c-sharp) . In my last question @p.s.w.g gives exact solution as i want . Now another situation comes into my mind that suppose we need to search `greater then 4` in a condition then what will we do .

**Detail**

In my last question i said the criteria will goes up to `1-4` , Suppose we include more criteria and give user a option to select `4+` and we will return all data where `Bedroom` is greater then four . What we will do in this case .

Suppose i got this in my filter variable `var filter = "1,4,4+";`

In this condition we should return user all `Listings` where Bedrooms are either `1` or `4` or `Greater then 4`.

**What I Have Tried**

```
var bedCriteria = "1,4,4+";
bedCriteria  = bedCriteria .Split(',').ToList();
bool isGreaterThenCriteria = bedCriteria.Contains("4+");
if (isGreaterThenCriteria)
{
     query = query.Where(l => l.Place.Bedroom > 4);
     bedCriteria.Remove("4+");
}

var minBeds = bedCriteria.Select(int.Parse);
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom.Value));
```

Comment: That won't work, because multiple `Where` clauses are the equivalent to one `Where` clause with all the conditions connected by AND. But you need OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on my previous answer, suppose you have this:

```
var minBeds = "1,2,4".Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom));
```

You can change this to...

```
var minBedStrings = "1,4,4+".Split(',');
var has4plus = minBedStrings.Contains("4+");
var minBeds = minBedStrings.Where(x => x != "4+").Select(int.Parse);
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom) || 
                         (has4plus && l.Place.Bedroom > 4));
```

If you want to handle something like `"5+"` or `"6+"` as well...

```
var minBedStrings = "1,4,4+".Split(',');
var nplus = minBedStrings.Where(x => x.Last() == '+')
                         .Select(x => (int?)int.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1))
                         .OrderBy(x => x)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
var minBeds = minBedStrings.Where(x => x.Last() != '+')
                           .Select(int.Parse);
query = query.Where(l => minBeds.Contains(l.Place.Bedroom) || 
                         (nplus.HasValue && l.Place.Bedroom > nplus.Value));
```

Comment: I don't have criteria like `5+` or `6+` . I have only `4+` , but there is a problem your first solution will not work we got only `4+` in filter string like this `var filter = "4+";`

Comment: When i select `4+` its giving all listing in which some are less then `4` . That's the problem

Comment: I don't see how. In this case, `minBeds` should be empty and `has4plus` should be true, so this should evaluate to `false || (true && l.Place.Bedroom > 4)` → `l.Place.Bedroom > 4`.

Comment: Sorry , I was a mistake by myself your code is working perfectly . Again thanks , Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you keep adding different filtering options you can try to parse filter string manually and than realize your predicate logic with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: What is the namespace of PredicateBuilder ?

Comment: it would be in that namespace where you put it)